# Applescript - Opening apps on different Desktops "Spaces"

Tags: applescript, desktop-application, desktop

I am very new to applescript, but was wondering if it is possible to open applications to different desktops "spaces" using applescript.  I have found how to launch applications, but don't know how to assign them to different desktops.  Basically I am looking to open;
Outlook - Desktop 1
Skype - Desktop 1
Safari - Desktop 2
Onenote - Desktop 3

Thanks for any help, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last system versions do not include any scripting of spaces. the only thing you can now do is to assign, in system preferences, shortcut keys to switch to a space, and once done, launch applications you want to.

To simulate action keys in Applescript, use system event "keystroke" instruction.

Comment: Thanks for your help, does automator include this function to assign workspace?

Comment: not in Automator. but you can assign key in system preferences, tab keyboard, select Mission Control and there are key for move to right space, left space or back to desktop 1. change your shortcut keys if you want and that's the keys you need to simulate in Applescript via keystroke command.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Easy: start these applications, one by one, in your "chosen" space, click on and hold Dock's icon, move cursor to "Options" (below), select this one (of three) options:

– Current desktop (or: this desktop, or similar)

… which from now on will always open THIS application in THIS space.

There is no programmatic way in AppleScript to instruct your Mac to switch spaces/workspaces or even to return the identity (number) of the current desktop.
Switching may happen, though, if the relevant option in System Preferences, Mission Control, is set.

(Indirectly, comparing a desktop "picture" to a user-defined list empowers a script to get its "number".)